# PHP single page form validation form not validating

Tags: php, html, css

Nothing happens when you click the submit button at the bottom of the page. I simply want it to validate user input and I am only focused on the name field at the moment and I cannot get it to validate any input in the name field. No error messages pop up or anything. Please review this and offer any suggestions, I cannot find my error.

PHP portion, where variables are initialized and set to empty. As well as the post methods and isset functions

```
<?php


//define variables and set them to empty values    

$fname_error= $phone_error= $address1_error= $address2_error= $city_error= $state_error= $zipcode_error= "";

$fname= $phone= $address1= $address2= $city= $state= $zipcode= "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
        $fname_error = "Missing";
    }
    else {
        $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
        //now we check to see that the name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
            $fname_error = "Please use letters and white space only";
        }
    }

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>
```

The Html portion:

```
                               <div class="userinput">
                                    <label for="fname"><b>First Name</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php 
                                         echo $fname ?>">
                                    <span class="error">
                                        <?php echo $fname_error;?></span>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Your submit button is not in the form.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I just moved it inside of the form tag and I still get nothing.

Comment: Im shocked to see someone trawled through an entire file worth of code. Its not often that happens, nor is it welcome most of the time on SO. In the future i would highly recommend posting relevant code only

Comment: I apologize! This is my first post here and I am not too familiar with the format. Will do for next time. Perhaps I will post an edited version of the question

Comment: You've also got a typo in your form's action attribute. It can be omitted when posting to the same page.

Comment: Please consider viewing my short answer; it may be of some assistance.

Comment: Arihan, I deleted the second form action. I still can't seem to get the form to validate, however. I will post a condensed version of the code when the post limit time expires. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: There is no "post limit time," just click the edit button to edit your post.

Comment: Trimmed it way down, I cannot find any errors here but this does not run properly. Thanks

Comment: Your welcome Cody. Sincerely hope that you find an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. This is just a hypothesis, I may be wrong as I couldn't check the *entire* code, but you *cannot have more than 1 form on the same page*. Because, you need a single opening and closing form tag that wraps ALL form elements on your page. Form fields are only counted as part of a form if they are contained within the form elements. And you *do* have more than 1 form on the same page.

Also, you should consider minimizing your code to only what's needed.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I think what the last comment means is in your code you need a single opening and closing form tag that wraps ALL form elements on your page. Form fields are only counted as part of a form if they are contained withi on the form elements.

Comment: That's basically what I meant; thank you for explaining my point. Also: may I use your comment in my answer? It seems to be somewhat helpful.